# Sequence of solutions of an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following problem, which says

Let $f : E \to E$ be continuos; suppose $f(x) \leq M$. For each $n=1,2,...,$ let $x_n: [0,1] \to E$ be a solution to $x'=f(x)$. If $x_n(0)$ converges, show that a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ converges uniformly to a solution.

Using the fact that $f(x) \leq M$ i can fulfill the hypothesis of Arzelà–Ascoli theorem and prove that exist a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ that converges uniformly, but i believe that i only have convergence and i need to prove that such subsequence converges to a solution, in order to do that i get stuck since i really don't know how to approach it and don't know how to use the fact that $x_n(0)$ converges.

If someone could helping me with that, thank you in advance

Comment: How's $ x_n $ a solution? Is it a function of $x$?

Comment: Why do u say that? $x_n$ satisfies the equality $x^{'}_n(t) = f(x_n(t))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

-First try to prove that $x^{'}_n$ has a uniformly convergent sub-sequence.

-Use the following theorem:

> Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of differentiable functions defined on the
>   closed interval [a, b], and assume ${f^{'}_n}$ converges uniformly to a
>   function g on [a, b]. If there exists a point $x_0 ∈ [a, b]$ for which
>   $f_n(x_0)$ is convergent, then $f_n$ converges uniformly. Moreover,
>   the limit function $f = \lim  f_n$ is differentiable and satisfies
>   $f^{'} = g$

-Finish the exercise

Comment: in the first part of the hint u say, prove that $x^{'}_n$ has a uniformly convergent sub-sequence, did u mean $x_n$ instead of $x^{'}_n$?

Comment: No, I mean $x^{'}_n$

Comment: so, in the part of the theorem that says "and assume $f_n$ converges uniformly to a function $g$" it should be $f^{'}_n$ instead of $f_n$? because i believe u want me to set $f_n = x_n$, and also in the first part of the hint should i use Arzelà–Ascoli ? thank you for the help

Comment: Yes, you're right, I edited it!

Comment: thank you, i already solved the problem, i knew that i was missing something, in this case i didn't remember that theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that $x_n(0)$ converges in order to prove that $x_n$ is uniformly bounded (and you need to know that, if you want to apply Ascoli-Arzelà!).

This is clear if you apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to your sequence of solution:
$$
x_n(t) = x_n(0) + \int_0^t f(x_n(s)) ds.
$$